# Jenkins xvnc plugin, some display numbers stay allocated when a build is stopped aburptly (ie jenkins restart) and cannot be used again

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, vnc

I am using Jenkins with the Xvnc plugin to run acceptance tests on Firefox in a CentOS slave . I have limited the display numbers to 2-4 since there will be at most 3 instances of testing that need a display. The tests and plugin work fine until Jenkins had to be restarted a few times due to issues in other builds.  The following error now occurs whenever the build tries to run:

```
FATAL: All available display numbers are allocated or blacklisted.
allocated: [2, 3, 4]
blacklisted: []
java.lang.RuntimeException: All available display numbers are allocated or blacklisted.
allocated: [2, 3, 4]
blacklisted: []
    at hudson.plugins.xvnc.DisplayAllocator.doAllocate(DisplayAllocator.java:59)
    at hudson.plugins.xvnc.DisplayAllocator.allocate(DisplayAllocator.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc.doSetUp(Xvnc.java:99)
    at hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc.setUp(Xvnc.java:89)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper.setUp(SimpleBuildWrapper.java:146)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
```

I checked a working build where I restarted Jenkins without manually stopping each job and found potential cause:

```
Terminating xvnc.
FATAL: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:296)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:815)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1034)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.handle(Channel.java:484)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.handle(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:61)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$2.run(NioChannelHub.java:594)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to jenkinstest.build.thoughtwire.com.test(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1361)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:171)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:954)
    at hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc$DisposerImpl.tearDown(Xvnc.java:183)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper$EnvironmentWrapper.tearDown(SimpleBuildWrapper.java:175)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:173)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1034)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.handle(Channel.java:484)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.handle(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:61)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$2.run(NioChannelHub.java:594)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Command close created at
    at hudson.remoting.Command.<init>(Command.java:56)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1028)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1026)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1109)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1092)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1033)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.handle(Channel.java:484)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
```

It seems like the job did not close properly and the Xvnc plugin did not get a chance to deallocate the display. I made sure the processes and tests in the slave are properly terminated and nothing is running.

The core issue here is that display numbers 2, 3, and 4 are now permanently allocated and cannot be reused even though no builds are running. If the slave (TEST) is mirrored (TEST2) then TEST2 can use display 2, 3, and 4 but TEST cannot. I have tried reinstalling the plugin but the numbers stay allocated and linked to TEST.

Does anyone know of a way to clear the list of allocated display numbers?
Is this a bug with the plugin?
Is there a way to prevent display numbers from staying allocated if say Jenkins suddenly dies while jobs are running?

Answer (score 1):

The allocated display number is saved in hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc.xml file on the jenkins master (under jenkins home directory). To clear the numbers, you need to stop jenkins, clean up <allocatedNumbers> in that xml, and start jenkins server again.

It is important to edit the file after you stop jenkins server, since jenkins will save the current numbers when it stops.

Answer (score 0):

This is a groovy script I created to clean up the Xvnc display numbers without stopping jenkins. But it might also clean up numbers of still running jobs.

https://github.com/sdiepend/jenkins-monitoring/blob/master/cleanXvncDisplayNumbers.groovy

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getActiveInstance();
xvncDescriptor = jenkins.getDescriptorByType(hudson.plugins.xvnc.Xvnc.DescriptorImpl.class)

xvncDescriptor.allocators.each {
  allocator = it.value
  // collect is used to make sure numAlloc is an entire new list and not just a reference to the same list object, otherwise you'll get a
  // concurrentmodification exception
  numAlloc = allocator.allocatedNumbers.collect()

  numAlloc.each {
    allocator.allocatedNumbers.remove(it)
  }
}
```